# Progress 4gl - cURL soap response

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I was recently asked if I knew how to decompose a cURL SOAP response with progress 4gl 10.1 framework despite the limitations. Is there a disconnect and they mean to parse through the response  as I don't recall decompose in anything progress 4gl related. Also, any recommendations on followup questions besides getting an example of the response? And if there is a disconnect verify they mean parse through the response.

I've searched through the progress 4gl documentation and searched through the progress discussion boards and not finding anything.

Comment: You are right - knowing the response sample is key to answer. Also I assume that with 4GL 10.1 framework you refer to OpenEdge release 10.1. Note that this ancient release has only limited support for JSON. The Json object model was only introduced in OpenEdge 11 or so.  I'm not sure if a temp-table's READ-JSON was already there in that historic release.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of mechanisms you can use to read SOAP responses (assuming they are XML). They have all been available in ABL for a long time (almost certainly in the 10.x releases).

1. You can call the SOAP service from within the ABL. See https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-develop-soap-clients/page/ABL-SOAP-Clients.html?labelkey=product_openedge_127 for more.
2. You can read (any) XML using the DOM (X-DOCUMENT and related widgets) https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-use-xml/page/Develop-XML-enabled-ABL-applications-with-DOM.html has more.
3. You can read (any) XML using the SAX parser. See https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-use-xml/page/Read-XML-Documents-with-the-Simple-API-for-XML-SAX.html?labelkey=product_openedge_127 for details.

The latter 2 are all part of [this document](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-use-xml/page/Develop-with-XML-in-OpenEdge.html)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that all these solutions are viable in version 10.1 as mentioned in the question. And even if they are Openedge 12 as referenced in a couple of links will likely have other features. So take that in mind!